# Where is this backward_warning.h #warning coming from?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-warnings, deprecated

Without looking through every single source file in my XCode project, is there a way to find out which #include is triggering the following warning?

```
#warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. 
Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the 
C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> 
header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header 
<iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
```

Clicking on the error in XCode just opens the backward_warning.h file, which is totally useless.

I know what the warning means, I know how to fix it (when I see the file in question and can look at its #includes)... but I just don't know how to find the file causing the error!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `-H` option to GCC - that will list the header files that are being included (along with a nesting indication so you can see what file is including which header).

With `-H` the error will be placed in the output stream clearly showing how the compiler got to `backward_warning.h`.

For example, when I include `hash_map`, I'd see:

```
mikeb@ubuntu:~$ g++  -H -c test.cpp
. /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/hash_map
.. /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/hash_map:60,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28: warning: #warning This file
includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without
further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent 
functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult 
the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

... a bunch of snipped output ...
```

As an aside, `/showIncludes` performs the same function in MSVC.

Comment: That worked. Found I'd got my own 'Vector.h' (that does math-based vectors, not STL Vectors) that the compiler was confusing with the STL Vector header. A small bit of file renaming and the warning has gone.

Would never have found that just by looking at the headers as 'Vector.h' was a piece of my own code.

Comment: @Piku: Chalk one up to the case-preserving but case-insensitive MacOS file system.  Maybe you could/should use the `#include <project/Vector.h>` (or `#include "project/Vector.h"`) mechanism to isolate your headers from system headers.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, the file `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/backward_warning.h`
contains the text you quote.  The headers which include `backward_warning.h` are:

- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/algo.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/algobase.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/alloc.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/bvector.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/complex.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/defalloc.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/deque.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/fstream.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/function.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_map.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hash_set.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/hashtable.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/heap.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iomanip.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iostream.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/istream.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iterator.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/list.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/map.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/multimap.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/multiset.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/new.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/ostream.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/pair.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/queue.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/rope.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/set.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/slist.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/stack.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/stream.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/streambuf.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/strstream`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/tempbuf.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/tree.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/vector.h`

Therefore, the code you are compiling must be including a header such as:

```
#include <vector.h>
```

instead of the preferred:

```
#include <vector>
```

And the compiler is getting fussy about it.  The fix is to find the code which includes the pre-standard header and update it to use the standard header.

(You get similar warnings about deprecated functions if you compile `git` - the functions are the SHA1 functions from OpenSSL.  It is a nuisance, to be polite about it.)

Answer (score 0):

You have an old style header somewhere.

something like this

IE:

```
#include <iostream.h>  //instead of <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>    //instead of <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>    //instead of <cstdio>
```

if it is included from a library then I think you are SOL, I personally wouldn't rummage through a library to get it to work you will have to up date them to use namespaces. and other such.