# bvector.h fatal error no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header

I use a program that includes the following headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bvector.h>
#include "eclat.h"
```

but when built it gives this message:

> `g++ -O3 -c enumerate.cpp`
>   enumerate.cpp:2:21: fatal error: bvector.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
>   compilation terminated.
>   Makefile:22: recipe for target 'enumerate.o' failed
>   make: *** [enumerate.o] Error 1

if I change to `bvector.h` to `vector`, the code doesn't work and generates more errors.

Comment: That's not a standard header, you need to figure out where it's supposed to come from and install the required library.

Comment: i old  version of C++ you can find <bvec.h>

Answer (score 2):

bvector.h is not a standard C++ header file. The '< >' syntax, while including headers is only applicable for standard header file.

For example stdio.h will be included as `#include <stdio.h>` in the program. If bvector.h is your header file, you can include is using " " syntax, like `#include "bvector.h"`.

Source: [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)

Comment: i think it was a header in the version 4.2.1 in the folder backward, but i don't with wich header it was replaced

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `< >` syntax for standard headers. bvector.h seems to be your include, so use `" "` instead:

`#include "bvector.h"`

Comment: i think it was a standard header but deprecated, because i find in another post that it was included in the version 4.2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280320/where-is-this-backward-warning-h-warning-coming-from

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code instead of #include . It seems to be an old file and no more (if ever) in the standard.

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> > bit_vector;
```

You can check [this file](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html-4.1.2/bvector_8h-source.html) for example.

Comment: It was never part of ISO/IEC 14882, i.e. "the standard".